# How to search a object in parse and if match then put into xml in android

Tags: android, jquery, parsing, object

I have some parse data and i want to put it in Layout's TextView if it match and  with layout tag and then layout visibility VISIBLE. I have some tag as Integer in Parse.But bellow program is not work. How can i do this?

```js
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("JhonaVerity");
        query.addAscendingOrder("Tag");
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {

                if ( e == null && objects != null){
                    for (final ParseObject object : objects){

                        Integer tag = object.getInt("Tag");

                        String VerityName = object.getString("VerityName");
                        String LifeCircle = object.getString("LifeCircle");
                        String Hight = object.getString("Hight");
                        String Weight = object.getString("Weight");
                        String Info = object.getString("Info");

                        Integer Like = object.getInt("Like");
                        Integer Dislike = object.getInt("Dislike");
                        Integer Comment = object.getInt("Comment");
                        Boolean boolean5 = object.getBoolean("Visibility");


                        if (tag.equals(mWholePannel1.getTag()) && boolean5.equals(true)) {



                                            mVarityName1.setText(VerityName);
                                            mTimePeriod1.setText(LifeCircle);
                                            mHight1.setText(Hight);
                                            mWeight1.setText(Weight);
                                            mInfo1.setText(Info);

                                            mLike1.setText(Like);
                                            mDislike1.setText(Dislike);
                                            mComment1.setText(Comment);
                                            if (boolean5.equals(true)) {
                                                mWholePannel1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                            } else {
                                                mWholePannel1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            }


                        }



                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: where is the problem? From where you want to get the data? Network or Local Storage?

Comment: From network to app

Comment: Is your network code alright? Did you check it?

Comment: The problem is that when loop then if parse aws data is match with the layout tag then layout show and and that (row data which is matched) add into layout textview.

Comment: Isn't the objects mapping properly?